# How to use scanf or use a different input reading method?

Tags: c, scanf

Newcomer to C here and struggling a bit.

I'm reading input that looks like this:

```
9, 344, 100
10, 0, 469
...
```

I am trying to group each line so that I can send each 3 numbers as parameters in a function.

I have been trying to use `scanf` but because it maps to memory addresses, I am having a problem with retaining the numbers after each line. I don't know how many lines of data I will have so I cannot make a certain number of arrays. Also, I am limited to functions in `<stdio.h>`.

If I use `scanf` is there anyway for me to avoid using malloc?

I have attached an idea below. Looking for suggestions and maybe some clarification on how `scanf` works.

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious here.

```
int main() {
  int i = 0;
  int arr[9]; //9 is just a test number to see if I can get 3 lines of input
  char c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    scanf("%d", &arr[i + 1]);
    scanf("%d", &arr[i + 2]);
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", arr[i],
      arr[i + 1], arr[i + 2]); //serves only to check the input at this point
      //at this point I want to send arr 1 to 3 to a function
    i += 3;
  }
}
```

The output of this code is a bunch of memory addresses and some of the correct values interspersed.
Something like this:

```
0, 73896, 0
0, 100, -473670944
```

When it should read:

```
0, 200, 0
0, 100, 54
```

```
int main(){
    char c;
    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c != '\n'){
            int a;
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("%d ", a);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This code prints out the input correctly, but doesn't allow me to use `scanf` more than once in the while block without a memory problem.

Comment: You don't know what you are getting since you aren't checking the return value of scanf.

Comment: the function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  The code (depending on the `signness` of `char` on your compiler) will not recognize EOF.  Strongly suggest replacing: `char c;` with `int c;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to scan all three at the same time. You also need to match the commas (`,`) in the input.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[9];

    int i = 0;
    for(; i + 3 <= sizeof arr / sizeof *arr // check that there is room in "arr"
          &&                               // and only then, scan:
          scanf(" %d, %d, %d", &arr[i], &arr[i+1], &arr[i+2]) == 3;
          i += 3)
    {
        printf("%d, %d, %d\n", arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use `fgets` and `sscanf` for that.

```
char buff[64];

/* .......... */

if(fgets(buff, 63, stdin) != NULL)
{
    if(sscanf(buff, "%d,%d,%d", &arr[i], &arr[i + 1], &arr[i + 2]) != 3)
    {
        /* handle scanf error */
    }
}
else
{
    /* handle I/O error / EOF */
}
```

Comment: OP was also asking about avoid malloc. Number of lines is not known in advance

Comment: OP wants to solve X-Y problem. `malloc` or fixed size array. There is no other way

Comment: UV for proper `fgets()` / `sscanf()`. With `scanf()` alone you are one mal-formatted character or extra-character away from corrupting all input from that point forward...